# How to edit column name and table name according to old name in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I am encrypting table name and column name by shifting down a character letter by a number of slot given by the key.
   For example, when key=3, "A" becomes "D", "z" becomes "c", and "1" becomes "4".

Here is my code to load data:

```
USE testdata
GO
CREATE testtable
    (TREATMENT CHAR(20),
     PRICE INT)
GO

BULK INSERT testtable
FROM 'c:\testdata.txt'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO

SELECT * 
FROM testtable
GO
```

How could I do it? Do I need dynamic sql?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you altering the column names and the table names?

Comment: Yes, but have to do that according to the old table name and column name as you can tell.

Comment: I think obfuscating your database schema is a very bad idea. You are opening yourself to a whole world of hurt...

Comment: You're going to encrypt your schema with a Caesar cipher?

Comment: Seems yes, couldn't find something deal with column name and table name character by character.

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a procedure to alter string, but not sure how to use it on column name

```
create procedure encrypt 
  @ptext as varchar(500)
as 
begin
set nocount on
declare @key as tinyint = 3
declare @etext as varchar(500) = ‘ ’
declare @pc as varchar(1)
declare @i as smallint = 1
declare @n as smallint

set @n = len(@ptext)

while @i <= @n
begin 
set @pc = substring (@ptext, @i, 1)

if ascii(@pc) between 48 and 57 
begin
    if ascii(@pc) + @key < 58
        set @pc = char((ascii(@pc) + @key))
    else 
        set @pc = char((ascii(@pc) + @key)-10)
end

else if ascii(@pc) between 65 and 90 
begin
    if ascii(@pc) + @key < 91
        set @pc = char((ascii(@pc) + @key))
    else 
        set @pc = char((ascii(@pc) + @key)-26)
end

if ascii(@pc) between 97 and 122 
begin
    if ascii(@pc) + @key < 123
        set @pc = char((ascii(@pc) + @key))
    else 
        set @pc = char((ascii(@pc) + @key)-26)
end

set @etext = @etext + @pc
set @i = @i + 1
end
select @etext
end
```